# cannot open laravel.log - Permission error in ec2 Aws

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services

I'm installing a fresh project in laravel, and the project has been successfully installed but there's error while browsing it.

```
UnexpectedValueException

The stream or file "/var/www/html/sample/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream:
Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

This will most likely be due to the permissions on the file itself.

When you installed that application, usually you would go about changing the ownership of the application with `chown` & the permissions to it's files with `chmod`.

However, even if you have done this on installation, the log file may not have existed at that time. To temporarily fix this, find the log file an update it's permissions (`664` or `775` should do for now).

You would not want to do this manually every day however, so you would want to look for a solution to set the ownership or permissions when the log file is created.

---

Depending on your version of Laravel, you may be able to change the permissions on the log file in `config/logging.php`

```
    'single' => [
        'driver'     => 'single',
        'path'       => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'permission' => 0664,
        'level'      => 'debug',
    ],

    'daily' => [
        'driver'     => 'daily',
        'path'       => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
        'permission' => 0664,
        'level'      => 'debug',
        'days'       => 14,
    ],
```